Follow up email after interview
I was a shortlisted applicant for a faculty position 5 months ago. Then I had an interview, and then I was asked for recommendation letters. I sent a follow-up email after submission of recommendation letter and the head of department told me my profile has been moved to the next step. He said that maybe I will receive some news in early may. I have not received any update about status of my application yet. Shall I send a follow-up email to ask about that? Or it seems that my application has no been accepted.

Sorry, I know it is frustrating to be in such an uncertain state, but no one on the internet can tell you anything helpful. For the pros/cons of follow-up e-mails, there is some discussion in the linked post.
